# How to connect a monitor via an USB based VGA card?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, linux-mint, toshiba-laptop

I want to connect two external monitors to my Toshiba Satellite C640, although I have only one VGA port. I have an external USB to VGA card which I connected, but it did not detect the second monitor on the USB to VGA card.

I am trying to connect it via [this](http://www.grand.com.tw/con_multi_view.php?menu=2) adapter.

Does anyone know what is going on?

#### System Specs:

- **Laptop:** Toshiba Satellite C640
- **OS:** Linux Mint 14

Comment: I assume the USB to VGA adapter requires specific drivers. Did you check if they are available for Linux, and if so, did you install them? That type of hardware is unlikely to be plug-and-play, especially on Linux.

Comment: No I didnt check for drivers.

Comment: Is this question about using a single VGA port, or is it about using a USB video card?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have already used the VGA port to connect a Monitor. I want to connect another via a VGA-TO_USB converter in a USB port.

Comment: Then fix your title.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Fixed.

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta you should probably do that first.

Comment: Umm, this might be a bit dumb but you keep saying VGA **to USB**, don't you need USB **to VGA**? A VGA to USB adapter would be a capture card, and could only take video in, not send it out. Can you tell us who makes your adapter and what its model number is?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think you are right. It should be a USB to VGA adapter. So how do I figure our my adapter model number?

Comment: Well you bought it right, what is it called? for example [this thing's](http://www.vgacapture.com/vga2usb-lr-frame-grabber/) is made by "VGA Capture" and its model is "VGA2USB LR", all I am asking is who makes your adapter and what do the people that make it call the product?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Okay. so it has a a usb in port and a vga out. also it has a hdmi out. Its called Grand Multi View. My friend succesfully used it in his macbook. I have borrowed it from him.

Comment: Model no. is P498

Comment: So are you talking about [this product](http://www.grand.com.tw/con_multi_view.php?menu=2)? If so, please edit your original question and include a link to it so people can see.